# Does the .Net Core System.Data.Sqlite library work on a Linux environment?

Tags: linux, .net-core, system.data.sqlite

I am using the System.Data.SQLite package in a .Net core app.
The dll runs fine in a Windows environment.

It does not run in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04).

**I have tried the following versions:**

> - version 1.0.03.0
> - version 1.0.113.7

**I get the following error message:**

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
> or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.113.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'. The located assembly's manifest
> definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040) File
> name: 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.113.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'

What do I need to do to make this run in Linux?

Comment: how are you deploying your application for linux? something like this? `dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64` ?

Comment: @Andy - The issue is not publishing to Linux. I'm publishing other apps to Linux with no issues. That part is fine. It's the actual DLL that's causing issues.

Comment: The short answer is "no". I have tried everything but witchcraft with 1.0.115. If I was cynical, I might think they've gone to great lengths to ensure that it does /not/ work cross platform.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite) (≥.Net6) works for me, both windows and linux.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite --version 6.0.13
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to use 1.0.118 version of System.Data.SQlite when trying to deploy WebApp on Azure Linux  When I used 1.0.115.5, it worked.  Hope this helps.